# Detect USB Connection Event on STM32

Tags: events, embedded, usb, interrupt

I'm currently working with a USB-enabled low power device that I'm having a bit of trouble with. During normal operation, the system clock is set to a significantly slower speed (since this is a data logger only active once every few minutes, this isn't a problem). However, when the device is then plugged into a USB port on a computer, it needs to recognize this, initialize the USB stack (which I can do), and reset the system clock to full speed (I can do this, as well).

My problem, as you might have noticed, is the "USB Connected" event. I'm looking through the STM32 evaluation materials and they have in the IRQn table a "USB_FS_WKUP_IRQn", and the STM32 eval board also has USB-5V power routed to pin PE6, which can also act as WKUP3.

Do I need to enable an external interrupt for that pin, or is there a better way to detect such an event and set/reset the clocks as needed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: USB implementation differs between different series STM32 - you may need to be more specific STM32F0/1/2/3/4?  I wonder if this is handles by the [STM32Cube](http://www.st.com/stonline/stappl/productcatalog/app?page=partNumberSearchPage&levelid=FM147&parentid=1897&resourcetype=SW) tools?

Comment: Oh, sorry, it's an STM32L152ZD on the EVAL board, and the final uP will be in the same family.

Comment: which class are you using? CDC?

Comment: It's an HID Device, sorry, should have made that clear.

Comment: @ThomSirveaux First of all u should use hid device with a usb bank, this problem is found in most embedded devices, next if there is a wakeup irq event you should configure it as such...

Answer (score 0):

Basing on the interrupt name you mentioned I found [this](https://github.com/LonelyWolf/stm32/blob/5eb4b550b5324d282333658aa8d07d4878cab271/stm32l151rdt6-dev/vcom/hw_config.c#L59) implementation:

```
// Enable the USB Wake-up interrupt
NVICInit.NVIC_IRQChannel = USB_FS_WKUP_IRQn;
NVICInit.NVIC_IRQChannelPreemptionPriority = 1;
NVIC_Init(&NVICInit);
```

It seems you don't need much more. The implementation can differ from the STM32 family you use.

Answer (score 0):

I use the stm32l4

I set up an interrupt on the Vbus pin. 
While not in USB mode, configure the pin as a pull-down (so it isn't floating).
Your pin and interrupt line would be different, but

```
//Configure the pin

    GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStruct = {0};
   __HAL_RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();

    /*Configure GPIO pin : PA9 */
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pin = VBUS_Pin;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Mode = GPIO_MODE_IT_RISING;
    GPIO_InitStruct.Pull = GPIO_PULLDOWN;
    HAL_GPIO_Init(VBUS_GPIO_Port, &GPIO_InitStruct);

    /* EXTI interrupt init*/
    HAL_NVIC_SetPriority(EXTI9_5_IRQn, 0, 0);
    HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(EXTI9_5_IRQn);
```

//Configure the interrupt

```
      EXTI_ConfigTypeDef exti_conf;
      exti_conf.Line = EXTI_LINE_9;
      exti_conf.GPIOSel = EXTI_GPIOA;
      exti_conf.Mode = EXTI_MODE_INTERRUPT;
      exti_conf.Trigger = EXTI_TRIGGER_RISING; 
      HAL_EXTI_SetConfigLine(&hexti_vbus, &exti_conf);
```

And make sure you have an interrupt handler taken care of. Set a flag for going to USB in the interrupt handler. And you should be set.